# Executing an long equation in one clock cycle

Tags: fpga, verilog

I am using DE2-115 Board for doing traversal in a forest data structure in 50 MHz frequency. Multiple trees have been stored in on-chip ROM, now I need to set the address which can point to a certain node in a certain tree during the decision operation.

The address assignment will become an long equation like: (Using Verilog)

```
    vip_rom_addr_out_1 = (2251*( {total_tree_cnt[5:0], 1'b0} )) +
        + 75 + (now_i_1 - 15)*68 + leaf_cnt;
```

I found that this equation seems can not be calculated in one clock cycle(50 MHz), because the result shows that "vip_rom_addr_out_1" is not correct in the board.

Should I turn the equation into multiple pipelines? 
Are there any efficient methods for access a large number of trees in FPGAs that can allow memory access in one clock cycle?

Thanks for your suggestions.

### Data Structure Detail

Each tree is a full binary tree with 16 leaves.
Each address corresponding to 1 word(each word is 8 bits).

Some data are stored in each split of each tree, these data are listed below:
(splits means the nodes that have two children, total 15 splits in each tree)

```
1. Two data numbers "a0" and "a1", each number is 2 byte.
2. One data number "b" of 8 bits.
```

There are 68 number pairs (m, n) stored in each leaf, m and n are all 8 bits:

```
Leaf 0:
(m0_0, n0_0) 
(m1_0, n1_0)
(m2_0, n2_0)
...... 
(m67_0, n67_0)
------------
Leaf 1:
(m0_1, n0_1) 
(m1_1, n1_1)
(m2_1, n2_1)
...... 
(m67_1, n67_1)
------------
Leaf 2:
...
```

### Memory Detail

100 binary trees as mentioned above have been stored in 2-port on-chip ROM.

```
[For Tree 1]
address 0: [a0 for split 0, lower 8 bits]
address 1: [a0 for split 0, higher 8 bits]
address 2: [a0 for split 1, lower 8 bits]
address 3: [a0 for split 1, higher 8 bits]
...
address 28: [a0 for split 14, lower 8 bits]
address 29: [a0 for split 14, higher 8 bits]
--------------------------------------------
address 32: [a1 for split 0, lower 8 bits]
address 33: [a1 for split 0, higher 8 bits]
address 34: [a1 for split 1, lower 8 bits]
address 35: [a1 for split 1, higher 8 bits]
...
address 58: [a1 for split 14, lower 8 bits]
address 59: [a1 for split 14, higher 8 bits]
--------------------------------------------
address 60: [b for split 0]
address 61: [b for split 1]
address 62: [b for split 2]
...
address 74: [b for split 14]
-----------------------------------
address 75: m0 for leaf 0
address 76: m1 for leaf 0
address 77: m2 for leaf 0
......
address 142: m67 for leaf 0
-----------------------------------
address 143: m0 for leaf 1
address 144: m1 for leaf 1
address 145: m2 for leaf 1
......
address 210: m67 for leaf 1
-----------------------------------
...... 
-----------------------------------
address 1163: n0 for leaf 0
address 1164: n1 for leaf 0
address 1165: n2 for leaf 0
......
address 1230: n67 for leaf 0
-----------------------------------
address 1231: n0 for leaf 1
address 1232: n1 for leaf 1
address 1233: n2 for leaf 1
......
address 1298: n67 for leaf 1
-----------------------------------
......
-----------------------------------
......
address 2250: n67 for leaf 15
----------------------------------     


[For Tree 2]
address 2251: [a0 for split 0, lower 8 bits]
address 2252: [a0 for split 0, higher 8 bits]
......
```

I want to read the content of "m" in certain leaf, and I use the equation to access the memory: (all the index is 0-Based)

```
address_index = 2251*(Tree_Index) + 75 + (node_index - 15)*68 + (m_index);
```

Thus I use 3 registers from 3 counters:

```
total_tree_cnt is the index of Tree.
now_i_1 is the index of nodes, (now_i_1 - 15) is the index of leaf(0~15).
leaf_cnt is the index of m(0~67).
```

I use two states for reading the memory data, I set the "vip_rom_addr_out_1" in state_1 as mentioned above, after 2 rising edge clock have been triggered, the FSM jumps to state_2 and the data should be read, but I have checked the content of vip_rom_addr_out_1 and it got the wrong address (0x24d), and the data read from ROM seems like coming from address 0.

There are no errors during compilation.
Thus I think the speed of multiplication matters.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: The point of pipelining is that splitting the operation into stages and having one operation in progress at each stage, means you can potentially have a throughput of producing a result every clock even though a given operation takes a latency of several clocks to from start to finish.

Comment: Hi Peter, I took the liberty to break your equation so that is more readable. It would be very good if you could share the synthesizer error, what all these register are and where do they come from, an maybe you can also share a screenshot of the RTL schematic of that tiny bit. Doing it in 50MHz should definitely be possible on FPGA.

Comment: One clock cycle is one clock cycle. It doesn't depend on clock frequency. At 50 MHz, on cycle has a duration of 1/50000000s (or 20ns). Are you looking for an algorithm that can complete within a second? Or are you looking for O(1)?!?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have added more details in my question, any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Wow, you added a lot of info. One question, I do not understand the (node_index - 15), why is the -15 there? is your now_i_1 equal to the node index, plus 15? You need to look in how your synth makes the multiplication. Writing '*' in Verilog is not a very good idea usually.

Comment: Consider setting the size of the data elements to be power-of-2 size. For example, if the size of tree is 4096 instead of 2251, then a left shift (relatively less logic and faster) can replace the multiplication (which may synthesize to a sequence of shifts and additions). And you would be trading size (wasting ROM space although gaining logic space) vs speed.

Comment: I haven't used Altera, but there should be a timing report that tells you exactly where your logic/routing is taking too long. But you say there are no errors reported by the software? If your timing constraints are correct, then you may have a different issue, like a sensitivity list issue.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies, your suggestions are helpful. I found some bugs that have caused the memory output wrong, I've fixed it, I will modify my design according to your suggestions for trading size vs speed.  As for the (node_index - 15) mentioned above, a tree with 5 levels may have node_index ranged from 0~30(0-Based), and have 16 leaves, node_index larger than 15 represents a leaf, thus (node_index - 15) ranged from 0~16 can represent the index of a leaf. Very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts:

- Making sure you can use powers of 2 (and a suggestion to do so);
- Helping the synthesis tool.

A. Making powers of two.

Unfortunately a simple change to powers of two makes you change from 2228 to 4096 and from 68 to 128.  That would require almost four times the memory range ... .

You could split 2228 in 2048 + 180 resulting in 2048+256, and splitting 68 in 64 + 4 (already powers of two).
You'ld need to reorganise your data and test which equation to use based on leaf_data for instance:

```
if(leaf_data[...]<30) then 
     vip_rom_addr_out_1 = (2048*( {total_tree_cnt[5:0], 1'b0} )) +
    + 75 + (now_i_1 - 15)*68 + leaf_cnt;
else 
     vip_rom_addr_out_1 = base_adr+(256*( {total_tree_cnt[5:0], 1'b0} )) +
    + 75 + (now_i_1 - 15)*68 + leaf_cnt;
endif
```

The equations above need to be reworked, the analysis needs some work.  The resulting code will be more complex to understand, but faster to execute.

I also note that the number of entries for leaf_cnt is already a power of 2 - you could replace your 2228*... with (16*2^n)*leaf_cnt and sum with total_tree_cnt instead.

To reorganise your data, write a small utility program in the language you prefer and validate your formula in that program (by checking known results for given input values).

B. Help the synthesis tool.

It is really more efficient to write your expressions in terms of the computing blocks that you expect rather than feeding a complex expression into the synthesis tool.

For example, you should not write:

```
if(leaf_data[...]<30) then 
     vip_rom_addr_out_1 = (2048*( {total_tree_cnt[5:0], 1'b0} )) +
    + 75 + (now_i_1 - 15)*68 + leaf_cnt;
else 
     vip_rom_addr_out_1 = base_adr+(256*( {total_tree_cnt[5:0], 1'b0} )) +
    + 75 + (now_i_1 - 15)*68 + leaf_cnt;
endif
```

but

```
vip_rom_addr_out_1a = (2048*( {total_tree_cnt[5:0], 1'b0} )) +
    + 75 + (now_i_1 - 15)*68 + leaf_cnt;
vip_rom_addr_out_1b = base_adr+(256*( {total_tree_cnt[5:0], 1'b0} )) +
    + 75 + (now_i_1 - 15)*68 + leaf_cnt;

if(leaf_data[...]<30) then 
     vip_rom_addr_out_1 = vip_rom_addr_out_1a;
else 
     vip_rom_addr_out_1 = vip_rom_addr_out_1b;
endif
```

This second alternative will hint th synthesis tool that you expect it to create two computation modules and a multiplexer which is probably more efficient than a large block of logic.

Factoring your expression will also help for resource reuse, etc:

```
leaf_offset=75 + (now_i_1 - 15)*68 + leaf_cnt;
vip_rom_addr_out_1a = (2048*( {total_tree_cnt[5:0], 1'b0} )) +
    + leaf_offset;
vip_rom_addr_out_1b = base_adr+(256*( {total_tree_cnt[5:0], 1'b0} )) +
    + leaf_offset;
```

Keep in mind that there is no predefined structure for a sum of three terms, only for two.  So making sure that you only sum two terms at a time helps the tool recognize the adder, and setting priority.  If you sum 4 terms, sum them two by two and then the result of these two intermediate results.

If some of the values correspond to a setting that does not change for a while, you should be able to limit their negative influence on the frequency (by latching them in a register, by instructing your tool to suppose that the signal is stable for timing analysis, ...).

I agree that tools optimise, but not as much as you'ld think for hardware synthesis.  After synthesis make sure that the tool created the expected adders, multipliers, multiplexers, etc.  If not, check the documentation for pragmas that you can add to your source code.

C.
The same kind of work is needed in order to pipeline.  Instead of defining the above as unclocked intermediate results, you'ld have to clock them (other signals may also need to be pipelined).

D.
Know how much you are short of reaching 50MHz and where you loose computation time.  I remember speeding up circuits by a factor of two and reducing their size by 2 with techniques like the above.  The speedup can be pretty high if you can introduce multiplications with factors of two (in the end you only have a few sums and a multiplexer).
Try to estimate the gain you can achieve and determine if you need pipelining or not.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciated your time and effort, I am extremely grateful for your help, I'll modify my data structure and code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

How important is it that you use those specific addresses and put all of that in one RAM? Consider partitioning things differently so that you can replace all of the constants in that equation with powers of two. This will remove the need for hardware multipliers and you will actually be able to run the computation in a single clock cycle. Also, partitioning the tree across multiple block RAMs could simplify the address computation by removing some of the offsets that are added or subtracted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll try to optimize my design as your suggestions.